# What means: libtool: -dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -ObjC

Tags: iphone, linker, static-libraries

I inherited a project (lucky me!) which relies on a static library.  Trying to build the static lib, I get this error:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool: -dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -ObjC
```

It is followed by these two lines, which I *do* understand, but this appears to be a separate problem (missing file.)

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lFlurryWithLocation
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lFlurryWithLocation is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1
```

Am I wrong, and it's all related?  Will the 1st line error go away if I fix the missing file part?

Either way, what does the `-dynamic not specified` part of message mean?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the args you're passing to libtool?

Comment: In iPhone development, many 3rd party libs require that you add the linker flag -ObjC as a project build setting.  (Paragraph) I fiddled with the project for a while and, magically, the error went away.  I can't really say what I did, sorry.  I'd love to know from someone who understands the inner gerwerkkens of libtool what the `-dynamic not specified` bit means, though!

Answer (score 0):

Olie, your original hunch was correct. There is no relationship between the two messages. The first message '-dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -ObjC' is just a warning. The -objC option is not needed for building a static library.

Comment: -1 This isn't a warning, it is actually an error and prevents a successful build.

Comment: Perhaps it would have been better if I said the warning is unrelated to the error.